# How to increase and check number of successful ssh connections to a remote host

Tags: ssh, sshd, ssh-config, connectivity, parallel-ssh

I wrote the below loop that creates ssh connections to remotehost1

```
$ cat sshloop.sh
#!/bin/sh
i=0
while [ $i -ne 500 ]
do
                i=$(($i+1))
                echo "SSH COUNT IS: $i"
                       ssh oracle@remotehost1 'uptime'
                done
```

This scripts runs and makes all 500 ssh connections to remotehost1.

However, when i change the script to make connections to remotehost2 `ssh oracle@remotehost2 'uptime'` it hangs / stops after 20 connections only.

Where can i check this limit of 20 ssh connections only; and how can i increase it?

remotehost2 is

```
$ uname -a
SunOS remotehost2 5.11 11.4.34.94.4 sun4v sparc sun4v
```

The issue seems to be with the nofile value on remotehost2 which is far less than what we have on remotehost1 where it works fine. The issue could be something else as well. I m not sure as of now.

Can you tell me the command to increase the nofile value on solaris?

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Fwiw, your loop is not running ssh in parallel, but in sequential order.

Comment: As A.B pointed out, your ssh connections are not in parallel so searching in ssh settings will probably not give you an answer. My guess would be connections are limited with firewall. Here is an example https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-limiting-ssh-connections-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-debian/.

Comment: As the others have stated, at no point do you have multiple SSH connections/sessions running.

Comment: @All i agree these are serial connections but where is the limit for only 20 such connections made so i could increase it?